# Form textbox problems with overflow and position of the text

Tags: html, css, forms

I want a textbox that has the parameters: width:450px and height:150px.
I don't want the text to overflow and start from the top.

My text somehow starts in the middle of the box and overflows at the end instead of breaking.

```
Startseite:</br> <input style="height:150px; width:450px;" type="text" name="Startseite" value=""></br></br>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FTkT2/1/

Comment: you have to use textarea instead of textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `textarea` instead of `input`.

Referring to your fiddle:

```
MyField:</br> <textarea style="height:150px; width:450px;" type="text" name="myField" value=""></textarea></br></br>
```

You can also use `cols` and `rows` attribute for size.

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of a `input` with the type of `text` you need to use a `textarea`. For example

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use textarea :

```
<textarea style="height:150px; width:450px; overflow: auto; vertical-align: top;"  name="myField"></textarea>
```